# how to write a query in orientDB to store array of data

Tags: orientdb

How to store and retrieve array of data in orientDB. eg array of hobbies 
{
  'hobbies':[
     'cooking',
     'dancing'
  ]
}

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
 INSERT INTO V SET hobbies = [ 'cooking', 'dancing' ]
```

And

```
 SELECT FROM V WHERE hobbies CONTAINS 'cooking'
```

Comment: thanks for your response. but still i have few questions. 1) how will i create a property which will store array of data of specific types ie; only integer or char. 2) And also how to avoid duplicate entries in the array.